# A term for providing irrelevant and hiding relevant information

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

For example, you're doing a research for a car to purchase. You get a list of cars with engine number, city where a car was assembled, and a color. What's missing is make, model and price.

Comment: Misinforming, maybe?

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it's done deliberately, it's obfuscation.

Answer (score 5):

The irrelevant information could be described as a *[smokescreen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smokescreen)*.

Answer (score 3):

To *sidetrack* is to direct a person's attention away from the relevant subject to an irrelevant one.

Answer (score 2):

Specifications can be slanted, imperfect, flawed, missing, incomplete, deficient, deceptive, blemished, embellished, camouflaged, cherry-picked, or corrupt because of mendacity, laziness, misinformation, turpitude, equivocation, double dealing, a shell game, forgetfulness, delay, propagandizing, or random error; no one word will fit all cases.
Other possibly related phrases: *pull the wool over your eyes, sell you some snakeoil, rigamarole, specmanship*.